# Loading EXIF data from currently displayed image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, exif, galleria

I am in the current situation:

I am developing a site for publishing my photos. I am using twitter bootstrap, jquery and [Galleria.io](http://www.galleria.io)

Now i want to show some exif data from the photos i made. Therefore i want to use this jquery plugin: http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/jquery-exif-data-plugin.html

I have already tested the examples give on the side. They work.
The code below doesn't. It returns an empty alert, everytime the image is loaded.
So at least this works.
These are my first steps in javascript, so i am glad for every help.

The exif data should be updated everytime I change the image. All images are located on the same server.

```
Galleria.ready(function(options) {
    // this = the gallery instance
    // options = the gallery options
        this.bind('image', function(e) {
            imgHandle = $(e.imageTarget)
            imgHandle.load(function() {
                $(this).exifLoad(function() {
                    alert($(this).exifPretty());
                });
            });
        });
    });

    $("#img2").load(function() {
        $(this).exifLoad(function() {
            alert($(this).exifPretty());
        });
    });
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: A good idea may be to skip the `Galleria` part and just concentrate on getting the `exif` plugin working first.

Comment: I already tried that too. It seems the developer of this script isn't maintaining it anymore. There are probably incompatibilities to the new jQuery version.

Comment: Okay i tested it with jQuery 1.2.3 . The realease when the script was released. Still no reaction....

Comment: My guess is that that you're doing something wrong here. Try just getting one of the authors examples working.

Comment: The authors example work fine. I already know that you cant get remote picture exif, but i only have local ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured it out with a friend:

My code now looks like this:

```
Galleria.ready(function(options) {
    // this = the gallery instance
    // options = the gallery options
    // will be called after the image is loaded
        this.bind('image', function(e) { 
            imgHandle = e.imageTarget;
            alert('Image loaded');
            //will be called if on same server
            $(imgHandle).exifLoad(function() {
                alert('Exif loaded');
                alert($(imgHandle).exifPretty());
                //do something here....
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

And it works only with images on the server but not on remote servers.